# Custom HTML in a day with FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Is there a way to add, specifically, form elements for every day that are distinguishable per day?  Below is an example.

I know FullCalendar is built to handle "Events", so from what I can tell in the docs, it's not really possible.  But I'm not a Javascript guru either, so would anyone else know of a solution?  I'm hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting idea which I haven't attempted yet. I don't think there is a callback like onRenderDay(), so you'll probably have to hack it in there. I'd suggest adding your code into the `viewDisplay` callback.  Something like this maybe:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        $("#calendar .fc-view-month td").append('<input type="checkbox"/>AM<br>');
    }
});
```

You may need to tweak the selector, perhaps use `.fc-grid`. You could also customize it to not include `<td>` elements with a class of `.fc-other-month`, so that only actual days of the currently viewed month will have the extra content in them and not days from the previous or next month that are in this month's view.

I'm assuming that any events will overlap on top of your content, so this might all be for naught anyway. Unless you aren't going to show events, in which case you could probably solve this better without fullcalendar.

Also, your image looks like you want just a single week to show. I don't thin that is possible with fullcalendar. Besides, if that is what you want, there would be much simpler ways to do it than using fullcalendar.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the image is just a sample of what I'm after, I am using a full month view.  And as you mentioned, I wouldn't be using events in this scenario, so I did end up just generating a calendar on my own.

I do like your suggestions though, and I will be looking into it further in the future.  I'll report back with anything I come up with.

Thanks for your help and feedback!

Comment: @drewjoh: fullcalendar is a pretty heavyweight component, and if you aren't using the events feature, it probably isn't worth using. But it is great for displaying events. You could also put an event in each day, and add the checkboxes inside of the event using the eventRender callback.